# Sending mail from command line on Linux is giving different results with the domain on two different servers

Tags: linux, email, postfix, email-server

I have configured Postfix, as well all of the appropriate server files to be the same on two different servers. These were configured at different times - but the files and settings match up, so `/etc/postfix/main.cf` and the `/etc/hosts`, `/etc/hostname`, `/etc/resolv.conf`, `/etc/mailname`, and so on all match up.

The part that is different, is that whenever I send mail from one of them via the command line using the mail command - I get different results from each unit and I can't for the life of me figure out what is different or where this variable is being pulled from the mail command.

- Host 1 (from /var/log/mail.log): `uid=1000 from=<operations>`
- Host 2 (from /var/log/mail.log): `uid=1000 from=operations@mail.contoso.com`

For whatever reason, the second host is appending the hostname after it. But the top host is leaving it bare, and because of that it's using the myorigin variable I have set in Postfix and is working as intended.

Something isn't matching up here - like I said all of my files are the same but just for comparison sake I'm posting my postconf -n below (it is the same on each host so no point to paste it twice - I have diffed them with Notepad++).

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
config_directory = /etc/postfix
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = mail.example.com, localhost.localdomain, localhost
myhostname = mail.example.com
mynetworks = 10.0.0.0/8 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = /etc/mailname
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost = smtp-relay.gmail.com
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
```

Comment: Please also give the command you are using to send the mail.

Comment: I was using `echo "insert anything here" | mail -s "insert anything here" myemail@contoso.com` to test the email. I actually figured out the issue and am about to update my post. I feel like I may have ran into a Postfix bug not properly using the `/etc/mailname`.

Comment: Please write an answer to your question instead of editing it. Also accept this answer so the thread is marked as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. For whatever reason, it seems like my /etc/mailname wasn't getting processed, even though it was identical to the other server - and the file even had the same MD5sum - the Postfix configuration wasn't taking it. I also noticed that I was using mailutils on one system (the one that wasn't working and had Postfix installed after the fact) and the other was using bsd-mailx. I swapped this before trying the /etc/mailname change, and it didn't seem to make a difference but for what it's worth I'm noting it just in case. Anyways I changed my /etc/mailname to a bogus value like test, then did a sudo postfix reload and sudo service postfix restart and then switched it back to what I intended it to be (contoso.com) followed by the same two commands to refresh the config and service, and lo-and-behold, it was working as intended. Thanks to all that helped.

Answer (score 0):

Scratch that - I missed that you said /etc/mailname in your original post... but I suppose the restart of postfix may still be relevant.

---

Check /etc/mailname if you have this file on your system. That will impact your outbound mail name.

```
root@purgatory:/home/me# cat /etc/hostname
purgatory.corp
root@purgatory:/home/me# cat /etc/mailname
aaaaaapurgatory.corp

postfix/qmgr[33605]: C8FEF2461048: from=<root@aaaaaapurgatory.corp>, size=367, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
```

Be sure to restart postfix after making edits to /etc/mailname.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately the `/etc/hostname` of each of them is identical :( I did a `sudo postfix reload` as well as a server reboot for good measure, then sent some mail from the command line and it's still appending it, darn!